# OpenLayers throws exception on every call after creating map

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to use OpenLayers 3.3.0 (tried 3.2.0 too) and I'm having some problems. Creating the `Map` object works fine but after that everything I call on the map objects simply fails.

A simple:

```js
myMap = new ol.Map({
  target: 'MainMap',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
        layer: 'sat'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

alert(myMap.getCenter());
```

doesn't work, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".
I am honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong, I looked in examples and tried looking for the issue but I can't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`Map`'s documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html) there's **no** `getCenter` method. However, calling `getView` returns an `ol.View` object that *"manages properties such as center (...)"*.

Copy-pasting your code in JS console directly on http://openlayers.org/ with the last line changed to:

```js
myMap.getView().getCenter();
```

prints:

> [4164462.1505763642, 985738.7965919945]

---

What do you mean by *"exception on every call after creating map"* and *"everything I call on the map objects simply fails"*? It's easy to verify in JS console that all documented methods work correctly.